# need to send invoice as mail from quickbooks online

Tags: php, phpmailer, quickbooks

Need to send invoice as mail from quickbooks online using PHP. I am using the [SDK](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) to integrate with quickbooks online. But I don't know how to send invoice using the SDK provided by consolibyte. Can anyone help me? I had downloaded the SDK from [this](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) link.

Answer (score 1):

Consolibytes SDK does not support send Api, but you can track the code inside to alter their functions and implement it.